# Kivy and RevMob error, it can't find the Java Class, not even in the example program

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, kivy, revmob

Here's my log:

```
File "/home/foo/bar/revmob/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
 from android import *
File "/home/foo/bar/android.py", line 5, in <module>
 RevMobNative = autoclass('com.revmob.RevMob')
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/jnius-1.1_dev-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/jnius/reflect.py", line 154, in autoclass
 c = find_javaclass(clsname)
File "jnius/jnius_export_func.pxi", line 25, in jnius.find_javaclass (jnius/jnius.c:16506)

 jnius.JavaException: Class not found b'com/revmob/RevMob'
```

Does anyone know where this class is in the RevMob files and where I need to put it for jnius to find it? I'm assuming it's just in the wrong location, but I'm not a Java guy.

Comment: I've discovered it does not work in the Kivy Launcher testing environment, but when I compiled it with Buildozer to test it, then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it has to be compiled for RevMob to run. Once I'd built it with Buildozer there were no problems. This means you can't use the Kivy Launcher to test apps with RevMob ads.